# Django Signals.py. How to combine receiver's and initiate function in a new thread

Tags: django, frameworks, signals, backend, receiver

which is the best way to combine Django receiver's from signals.py and initiate a function in a new thread.

Example with post_delete and post_save :

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Application)

def test_delete_function(sender, instance,  **kwargs):
    if isinstance(instance, Application):
          deletefunc()


@receiver(post_save, sender=Application)

def test_save_function(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(instance, Application):
          savefunc()
```

So, 
Q1: Is this a good way to express different receiver types - @receiver and then functions after that?

Q2: When saving Application from the fronend with POST,  test_save_function is initiated in the same thread. How to run test_save_function on a different thread? 
   - I expected this to be handled by Django Framework, but it seems I need additional configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why you would expect signals handlers to be run in a different thread. Python's support for multithreading is quite limited anyway so if you want to have a long or heavy function executed out of band, you want some async task queue (celery, huey etc).

Comment: wrt/ Q1: yes, this is the correct way to use [the decorator syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator) here - but we usually don't put a blank line in-between. **BUT** if `Application` is your own model, [using models signals here is an antipattern](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/)

Comment: Thread: The issue here is if backend - in our case "test_save_function" is awaiting POST to finish before it's initiated (also if POST failed, "test_save_function" will too ). I was looking for a way to initiate POST, it can took lets say 5 seconds, and in the same time to run "test_save_function" no matter if POST is finished or not.  Also strange thing in opposite direction is: if "test_save_function" takes 2 minutes, it will handle on POST request too. The blank line in-between is just syntax mistake when I posted the example. Application is my own model yes

Comment: I really suggest you follow the link I already posted about [signals antipatterns](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/) - it should clear up a lot of things for you. TL;DR : signals are NOT async, their only goal is to provide hooks for other apps. If you want out of band operations, use an async task queue.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, will check queues